# How do I get the hair in the render (right) to match the hair in the original model (left) ? can't seem to find a tutorial that covers this

Tags: particles, hair

[image]

How do I get the hair in the render (right) to match the hair in the original model (left) ? can't seem to find a tutorial that covers this.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you have some 'Clumping' and a higher hair density in the right picture.

The density raise is normal for (simple and interpolated) Hair Children. Maybe look in your Particle Settings for this section and set equal values for *Display Amount* and *Render Amount*. It might also solve the clumping effect:

[image]

Comment: maybe you should also vary the hair length a little